# Changing a buttons background on hover and click

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, triggers, styling

I am making a dashboard of sorts by using buttons. Based on the value of some object I change the `background` of the button. when the user hovers or clicks the button I want to change the background color to indicate its pressed. I have the following code:

```
<Button Height="100" Width="230" Command="{Binding Path=SetSelectedCollection}" CommandParameter="option1" >
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Item.IsOk}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#8FCE5D"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Item.HasWarnings}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFBE39"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Item.HasErrors}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#C01318"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>

            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />

            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                           <ContentPresenter/>                                                                                                           

                        </Border>

                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#E59400" />
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                                <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
                            </Trigger>

                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="OrangeRed" />
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

So the first part all works fine, I get the correct color buttons based on the the status of the item im binding too, however when i mouse over or select it the color does not change. The foreground color changes and the cursor changes but the background color does not. I don't understand why not. How can i achieve this?

Comment: My guess is that it is using the background you specified based on whether it has warnings, errors etc. instead of the background specified for the MouseOver or IsPressed properties. Why don't you change something other than the background? It seems like you are trying to display a lot of different information just using the background color.

Comment: I also tried to add a border, on the mouseover and ispressed and no effect either. Is there another approach i should be taking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the background color you are setting in the DataTriggers is overriding the ControlTemplate triggers. One solution is to change the border brush instead to indicate mouse over or mouse pressed. Another thought would be to add an icon to the button's template if the item has errors, etc. instead of changing the background color.

Here is your original code, modified so that it changes the border color for the mouse state, and retains the background coloring for IsOk/HasErrors/HasWarnings:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Item.IsOk}" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#8FCE5D"/>
    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Item.HasWarnings}" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFBE39"/>
    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Item.HasErrors}" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#C01318"/>
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>

<Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
<Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>

<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                <ContentPresenter/>

            </Border>

            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#E59400" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
                </Trigger>

                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="OrangeRed" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```